# Programmaticaly filter data in JavaScript with different types of logical conditions (AND/OR)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I am working with a dataset represented in the following way:

```js
data = [
  {
    GEO_ID: "36005000400",
    avg_tree_diam: "Low",
    life_expectancy: "Medium",
    median_income: "High",
    percent_not_alive: "Low",
    tree_density: "Low"
   },
  {
    GEO_ID: "36005001600",
    avg_tree_diam: "Medium",
    life_expectancy: "Medium",
    median_income: "Medium",
    percent_not_alive: "High",
    tree_density: "Medium"
  },
  {
    GEO_ID: "36005001900",
    avg_tree_diam: "Low",
    life_expectancy: "Low",
    median_income: "Low",
    percent_not_alive: "High",
    tree_density: "Low"
  }
];

filters = {median_income: ["Low", "Medium"],
           tree_density: ["Low"]};
```

I would like to write a function that applies an arbitrary number of filtering conditions, including keeping more than one value from the same attribute. This is why the values of my filter object are arrays.

So, in the example above, the filtering function would comb through the data and include in its output every entry with a median income level of Low OR Medium. At this stage, the first entry of the data would be excluded because its median income value is "High".

Then, the the second stage of filtering would occur, which would logically use an AND operator to include entries that have **both** the specified median_income values and the specified tree_density values.

I have found examples of filtering data in JS using an object to specify the filtering parameters, as I do, but all of the examples I have found can only isolate one value for each attribute. To reiterate, the main difference in my situation is that I have filtering parameters in an object that includes **arrays** as values, not single strings or integers.

I will only use this for categorical data, so there is no need to think about quantity comparisons.

Here is an approach I am thinking of taking:

1. Generate filtered datasets for each attribute in the filtering object via a loop. In this case, I would have two datasets: one that matches the median_income specifications, and one that matches the tree_density specifications.
2. Return the union of all of the individually filtered datasets (not sure how to do this in JavaScript, but I am hoping there is a fairly straightforward way).

Is this the approach you would take? Is there an easier way to think about this problem? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try coding the approach you describe? Can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this within a single [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) call, iterating over the properties of the `filters` object and using [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check each array of values against each object in the data array.

Here using a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to iterate the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) of the filters object as it allows one to return early if one of the `some()` calls returns false.

```js
function filterWithFiltersObject(data, filters) {
  return data.filter(obj => {
    for (let prop of Object.keys(filters)) {
      // as soon as one of the filters arrays doesn't have at least one match return false
      if (!filters[prop].some(filterValue => obj[prop] === filterValue)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    // if all of the filters arrays have at least some values that match return true
    return true;
  });
}

const
  data = [{ GEO_ID: "36005000400", avg_tree_diam: "Low", life_expectancy: "Medium", median_income: "High", percent_not_alive: "Low", tree_density: "Low" }, { GEO_ID: "36005001600", avg_tree_diam: "Medium", life_expectancy: "Medium", median_income: "Medium", percent_not_alive: "High", tree_density: "Medium" }, { GEO_ID: "36005001900", avg_tree_diam: "Low", life_expectancy: "Low", median_income: "Low", percent_not_alive: "High", tree_density: "Low" }],
  filter1 = {
    median_income: ["Low", "Medium"],
    tree_density: ["Low"]
  },
  filter2 = {
    median_income: ["Low", "High"],
    tree_density: ["Low"]
  };

console.log('filter1: { median_income: ["Low", "Medium"], tree_density: ["Low"] }')
console.log(filterWithFiltersObject(data, filter1));

console.log('\nfilter2: { median_income: ["Low", "High"], tree_density: ["Low"] }')
console.log(filterWithFiltersObject(data, filter2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

---

Alternatively you can use an [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) call in place of the `for...of` loop, also with a nested `some()` call.

The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. As soon as it encounters a `falsy` value it returns false. Here we are using it to check that *every property* in the filters object has at least one element in its array that matches the corresponding property in the object being tested.

```js
function filterWithFiltersObject(data, filters) {
  return data.filter(obj =>
    // check if every property in the filters object...
    Object.keys(filters).every(prop =>
      // ... has some elements that are equal to the same property in data object
      filters[prop].some(filterValue => obj[prop] === filterValue))
  );
}

const
  data = [{ GEO_ID: "36005000400", avg_tree_diam: "Low", life_expectancy: "Medium", median_income: "High", percent_not_alive: "Low", tree_density: "Low" }, { GEO_ID: "36005001600", avg_tree_diam: "Medium", life_expectancy: "Medium", median_income: "Medium", percent_not_alive: "High", tree_density: "Medium" }, { GEO_ID: "36005001900", avg_tree_diam: "Low", life_expectancy: "Low", median_income: "Low", percent_not_alive: "High", tree_density: "Low" }],
  filter1 = {
    median_income: ["Low", "Medium"],
    tree_density: ["Low"]
  },
  filter2 = {
    median_income: ["Low", "High"],
    tree_density: ["Low"]
  };

console.log('filter1: { median_income: ["Low", "Medium"], tree_density: ["Low"] }')
console.log(filterWithFiltersObject(data, filter1));

console.log('\nfilter2: { median_income: ["Low", "High"], tree_density: ["Low"] }')
console.log(filterWithFiltersObject(data, filter2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```